# Date string to NSDate conversion always get nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am trying to change date which I get from server in string format to convert it into NSDate formate.
    I used different type of format but I am always getting "nil".
    I would like to perform sorting operation by using date as key, for which I need to convert string date into NSDate object.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm:ss a zzzz"];
    NSDate *mydate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"Feb 09, 2016 - 18:47:35 UTC"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format you specified doesn't come remotely close to matching the format of the date string you wish to convert.

For that string you need:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy - HH:mm:ss z"];
```

Also, there is no need to set the time zone on the date formatter. The timezone will be obtained from the string being parsed.